# Why is nonlocal keyword needed for variables, but not needed for lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The following snippet is an example where we face an `UnboundLocalError` when accessing a nonlocal variable.

```
def foo(): 
    a = 1 
    def bar(): 
        a += 1 # Raises UnboundLocalError
        print(a) 
    bar() 

foo()
```

`a += 1` is evaluated as `a = a+1`. Here, the `a` on the RHS leads to an `UnboundLocalError`.

It can be fixed with the `nonlocal` keyword like so:

```
def foo(): 
    a = 1 
    def bar(): 
        nonlocal a # Fixes the UnboundLocalError
        a += 1 
        print(a) 
    bar() 

foo() # Prints 2
```

In the following snippet, we try to access a nonlocal list, but it does not raise an UnboundLocalError.

```
def egg(): 
    l = [[1 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)] 
    def chicken(): 
        l[0][0] -= 1 # Does not raise an UnboundLocalError
        l[1][1] -= 1 
        l[2][2] -= 1 
        print(l) 
    chicken()

egg() # Prints [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
```

The way I understand this, here as well, `l[0][0] -= 1` should have been evaluated as `l[0][0] = l[0][0]-1` which should have resulted in an `UnboundLocalError`. Why is that not the case?

Comment: You’re not *rebinding* any name by assigning to an index of a list. That’s the difference.